# Rotation & translation Matrix between rgb camera and IR sensor asus xtion PRO live

Tags: projection, calibration, asus-xtion

Anyone knows if there are some informations about transformation(Rotation and translation) between rgb camera and IR sensor? Calibration is the only way? 
I have to project 3D points on the RGB image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to perform the extrinsic calibration for this case.